# Replacing text with a string that contains (')

Tags: sed

I want to replace a line inside a file with another one that contains 'something something'. I tried achieving so by sed and using the back slash but it didn't work. I tried
's/original/'something something''
I inserted a backslash before each (') but it didn't work.

Any idea? I am happy to try a different tool if I can't achieve this using sed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If neither `original` nor `something something` contain other special characters, you can use outer double quotes:

```
$ echo 'original' | sed "s/original/'something something'/"
'something something'
```

Otherwise, you can close the outer single quotes, insert a literal (escaped) quote, then open the outer quotes again:

```
$ echo 'original' | sed 's/original/'\''something something'\''/'
'something something'
```

Comment: Thank you very much the first option worked for me.